# How can i add textbox inside dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add textbox inside dropdown list. Is there a way that i can use theadd textbox inside the dropdown ? thank you. I have using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the markup from the first example provided from [Dropdowns - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/), then you could use the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('<a>', {
    class: 'dropdown-item',
    href: '#',
    text: 'New Item'
  }).appendTo($('.dropdown-menu'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The important thing to consider is that you should change the appendTo selector to your actual item. With my example, if you had multiple DOM elements that had the `.dropdown-menu` class, then they'd all get appended the new element.